# Totally bounded metric space

Tags: analysis

> Consider $\Bbb{R}$ with the following metric:   $$\rho(x,y):=\left|\frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y |}\right|$$
>   Then I wish to show that $(\Bbb{R}, \rho)$ is a totally bounded metric space.

Of course by totally bounded I mean that  $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists a finite set $S\subset\Bbb{R}$ such that $\Bbb{R}\subset\bigcup_{x \in S} B_{\epsilon}(x)$.

Now this metric space is not complete, since $x_n=n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\Bbb{R}, \rho)$ which does not converge in the space, so I cannot use compactness. I have tried quite a few different things, all to varying degrees of success. How would I go about proving this?

Comment: You can consider the completion and show that that is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Show that the map

$$h:\Bbb R\to(-1,1):x\mapsto\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

is an isometry from $\langle\Bbb R,\rho\rangle$ to $\langle(-1,1),d\rangle$, where $d$ is the usual metric on $(-1,1)$; it’s easy to show that $\langle(-1,1),d\rangle$ is totally bounded.

Comment: Shall we duel? ${}{}{}$

Comment: Ah, thank you kindly. I'm not sure why I overlooked constructing an isometry - always seems clear when someone else has pointed it out.

Comment: @George: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @Pedro: I win: $8>6$, so $h$ beats $f$. :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Darn! ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\Bbb R\to (-1,1)$ with $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$. Then $f$ is an isometry of $(\Bbb R,\rho)$ with $((-1,1),d)$ where $d$ is the usual Euclidean distance.